# What should I look for in a window manager?

Tags: linux, window-manager, i3, window-management, bspwm

I'm looking into window managers for the first time and I don't really know how to compare them.

Can somebody please explain some things in the Wikipedia table head?

- Type (Stacking|Tiling|Dynamic etc.)
- ICCCM/EWMH compliant
- Tabbed windows

Also if you have any recommendations please leave them in comments. I was looking into i3, bspwm, awesome and a few others, but I couldn't really decide.

Comment: it is unclear what is your question ... you could just try a few window managers

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page for ICCCM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual The same applies to EWMH: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints

Comment: Please edit out the request for recommendations....

Answer (score 0):

I use [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/). It supports [tabs](http://fluxbox.org/features/) and is quite easy to customize it. I would never use a GUI, which I can not customize.

Tabbing means that you can arrange windows of programs in tabs, which do not implement tabs on there own as XTerm for example. And it can be done also with different programs. You can run Firefox, Emacs and XTerm with tabs in the window title. See the image on the Fluxbox features page.

Creating styles and changing the keys is very simple. I use `Mod4` (the "Windows" key) for most of the window manager specific stuff.  This are the keys I prefer most:

```
Mod4 Return :Fullscreen
Mod4 Prior :PrevWorkspace
Mod4 Next :NextWorkspace
```

I run most of my programms in fullscreen without decoration on different screens and switch through the virtual screen with "Windows-PageUp" and "-PageDown".

For Firefox it was necessary to disable autohide in order to keep the tabs visible.

```
browser.fullscreen.autohide;false
```

I also prefer plain XTerm with aliased Xft fonts ([Hack](https://github.com/source-foundry/Hack)). This requires a X11 customization which will be used by `xrdb`.

I also created my own desktop menu with different versions of XTerm for the notebook screen and my external monitor. The dpi values differ very much and X11 can not handle this right now (would require two different X servers).

I also prefer xim in `.xinputrc`:

```
run_im xim
```

This is all pretty old school but I like it. I hate Gnome hackers, who think they know best what is good for me.

This is my style:

```
! szi
! based on:
! meta
! (c) joel carlbark 2003
! please dont turn on aa with this style

toolbar:                             flat gradient vertical
toolbar.color:                       #849ec6
toolbar.colorTo:                     #526d8c

toolbar.button:                      parentrelative
toolbar.button.picColor:             #d6d7e7

toolbar.button.pressed:              sunken solid
toolbar.button.pressed.color:        #526d8c
toolbar.button.pressed.picColor:     #000000

! clock
toolbar.clock:                       parentrelative
toolbar.clock.textColor:             white

! shows workspace nr
toolbar.label:                       parentrelative
toolbar.label.textColor:             white

! current active window / toolbar
toolbar.windowLabel:                 parentrelative
toolbar.windowLabel.textColor:       white

! menu ---------
menu.title:                          flat gradient vertical
menu.title.color:            sienna
menu.title.colorTo:          tan
menu.title.textColor:            black

menu.frame:                          flat gradient vertical
menu.frame.color:                    #efefef
menu.frame.colorTo:                  #c6c3c6
menu.frame.textColor:                black

menu.hilite:                         flat solid
menu.hilite.color:           tan
menu.hilite.textColor:               black

menu.bullet:                         triangle
menu.bullet.position:                right

! window --------------
window.bevelWidth:                   2

window.roundCorners:                 TopLeft TopRight BottomLeft BottomRight
window.borderWidth:                  4
window.borderColor:                  peru

window.unfocus.borderColor:          silver

window.title.focus:                  flat
!gradient vertical
window.title.focus.color:            peru
!window.title.focus.colorTo:          tan

window.label.focus:                  parentrelative
window.label.focus.textColor:        white
window.label.focus.font:             sans-10:bold

window.button.focus:                 flat
!gradient vertical
window.button.focus.color:           peru
!window.button.focus.color:           #cd8c4b
!window.button.focus.colorTo:         #d1ac7f
window.button.focus.picColor:        black

window.button.pressed:               sunken solid
window.button.pressed.color:         tan
window.button.pressed.picColor:      black

window.handleWidth:                  8
window.handle.focus:                 flat gradient vertical
window.handle.focus.color:           tan
window.handle.focus.colorTo:         peru

window.grip.focus:                   flat gradient vertical
window.grip.focus.color:             tan
window.grip.focus.colorTo:           peru

window.frame.focus:                  flat solid
window.frame.focus.color:            white

! unfocused
window.title.unfocus:                flat
!gradient vertical
window.title.unfocus.color:          silver
!window.title.unfocus.colorTo:        lightgray

window.label.unfocus:                parentrelative
window.label.unfocus.textColor:      black

window.handle.unfocus:               flat gradient vertical
window.handle.unfocus.color:         #efefef
window.handle.unfocus.colorTo:       #c6c3c6

window.grip.unfocus:                 flat gradient vertical
window.grip.unfocus.color:           #efefef
window.grip.unfocus.colorTo:         #c6c3c6

window.frame.unfocus:                flat solid
window.frame.unfocus.color:          white

window.button.unfocus:               flat
!gradient vertical
window.button.unfocus.color:         silver
!window.button.unfocus.color:         #efefef
!window.button.unfocus.colorTo:       #c6c3c6
!window.button.unfocus.picColor:      #949694
window.button.unfocus.picColor:      white

! tabs ------
window.tab.justify:                  left

window.tab.label.focus:              flat
!gradient vertical
window.tab.label.focus.color:        red
!window.tab.label.focus.colorTo:      #526d8c
window.tab.label.focus.textColor:    white

window.tab.label.unfocus:            flat
!gradient vertical
window.tab.label.unfocus.color:      green
!window.tab.label.unfocus.colorTo:    #c6c3c6
window.tab.label.unfocus.textColor:  white

window.tab.borderWidth:              1
window.tab.borderColor:              white
! -------

toolbar.justify:                     left
window.justify:                      left
menu.title.justify:                  center
menu.frame.justify:                  left

borderColor:                         #000000
borderWidth:                         1
bevelWidth:                          1
frameWidth:                          1
handleWidth:                         4

background: flat
background.color: tan

*font:                               sans-10
```

This is my keys file.

```
# click on the desktop to get menus
OnDesktop Mouse1 :HideMenus
OnDesktop Mouse2 :WorkspaceMenu
OnDesktop Mouse3 :RootMenu

# scroll on the desktop to change workspaces
OnDesktop Mouse4 :PrevWorkspace
OnDesktop Mouse5 :NextWorkspace

# scroll on the toolbar to change current window
OnToolbar Mouse4 :PrevWindow {static groups} (iconhidden=no)
OnToolbar Mouse5 :NextWindow {static groups} (iconhidden=no)

# alt + left/right click to move/resize a window
OnWindow Mod4 Mouse1 :MacroCmd {Raise} {Focus} {StartMoving}
OnWindowBorder Move1 :StartResizing NearestCornerOrEdge

OnWindow Mod1 Mouse3 :MacroCmd {Raise} {Focus} {StartResizing NearestCorner}
OnLeftGrip Move1 :StartResizing bottomleft
OnRightGrip Move1 :StartResizing bottomright

# alt + middle click to lower the window
OnWindow Mod4 Mouse2 :Lower

# control-click a window's titlebar and drag to attach windows
OnTitlebar Control Mouse1 :StartTabbing

# double click on the titlebar to shade
OnTitlebar Double Mouse1 :Shade

# left click on the titlebar to move the window
OnTitlebar Mouse1 :MacroCmd {Raise} {Focus} {ActivateTab}
OnTitlebar Move1  :StartMoving

# middle click on the titlebar to lower
OnTitlebar Mouse2 :Lower

# right click on the titlebar for a menu of options
OnTitlebar Mouse3 :WindowMenu

# alt-tab
Mod1 Tab :NextWindow {groups} (workspace=[current])
Mod1 Shift Tab :PrevWindow {groups} (workspace=[current])

# cycle through tabs in the current window
Mod4 Left  :PrevTab
Mod4 Right :NextTab

# go to a specific tab in the current window
Mod4 1 :Tab 1
Mod4 2 :Tab 2
Mod4 3 :Tab 3
Mod4 4 :Tab 4
Mod4 5 :Tab 5
Mod4 6 :Tab 6
Mod4 7 :Tab 7
Mod4 8 :Tab 8
Mod4 9 :Tab 9

Mod4 x :Exec xterm
Mod4 p :Exec xsel -op | xsel -ib
Mod4 r :Reconfig
Mod4 space :WindowMenu

# volume settings, using common keycodes
# if these don't work, use xev to find out your real keycodes
176 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 1+
174 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 1-
160 :Exec amixer sset Master,0 toggle

# current window commands
Mod4 BackSpace :Close
#Mod1 F5 :Kill
Mod4 n :Minimize
Mod4 v :MaximizeVertical
Mod4 m :Maximize
Mod4 Return :Fullscreen

# open the window menu
#Mod1 space :WindowMenu

# exit fluxbox
#Control Mod1 Delete :Exit

# change to previous/next workspace
Mod4 Prior :PrevWorkspace
Mod4 Next :NextWorkspace

# send the current window to previous/next workspace
#Mod4 Left :SendToPrevWorkspace
#Mod4 Right :SendToNextWorkspace

# send the current window and follow it to previous/next workspace
#Mod4 Left :TakeToPrevWorkspace
#Mod4 Right :TakeToNextWorkspace

# send the current window to a specific workspace
Mod4 F1 :Workspace 1
Mod4 F2 :Workspace 2
Mod4 F3 :Workspace 3
Mod4 F4 :Workspace 4
Mod4 F5 :Workspace 5
Mod4 F6 :Workspace 6
Mod4 F7 :Workspace 7
Mod4 F8 :Workspace 8
Mod4 F9 :Workspace 9
Mod4 F10 :Workspace 10
Mod4 F11 :Workspace 11
Mod4 F12 :Workspace 12

# send the current window and change to a specific workspace
#Control Mod4 F1 :TakeToWorkspace 1
#Control Mod4 F2 :TakeToWorkspace 2
#Control Mod4 F3 :TakeToWorkspace 3
#Control Mod4 F4 :TakeToWorkspace 4
#Control Mod4 F5 :TakeToWorkspace 5
#Control Mod4 F6 :TakeToWorkspace 6
#Control Mod4 F7 :TakeToWorkspace 7
#Control Mod4 F8 :TakeToWorkspace 8
#Control Mod4 F9 :TakeToWorkspace 9
#Control Mod4 F10 :TakeToWorkspace 10
#Control Mod4 F11 :TakeToWorkspace 11
#Control Mod4 F12 :TakeToWorkspace 12
```

My `.Xresources`:

```
Xcursor.theme: Vanilla-DMZ-AA
Xcursor.size: 32

Xft.hinting: true
Xft.autohint: false
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.rgba: rgba

XTerm*.LoginShell: true
XTerm*saveLines: 16384
XTerm*jumpScroll: true
XTerm*faceName: Hack:size=10

XTerm*geometry: 160x50

XTerm*background: white
XTerm*foreground: black
XTerm*cursorColor: red
XTerm*highlightColorMode: true
XTerm*highlightColor: khaki
XTerm*highlightTextColor: black
XTerm*color0:     rgb:00/00/00
XTerm*color1:     rgb:80/00/00
XTerm*color2:     rgb:00/80/00
XTerm*color3:     rgb:80/80/00
XTerm*color4:     rgb:00/00/80
XTerm*color5:     rgb:80/00/80
XTerm*color6:     rgb:00/80/80
XTerm*color7:     rgb:c0/c0/c0
XTerm*color8:     rgb:80/80/80
XTerm*color9:     rgb:aa/00/00
XTerm*color10:    rgb:00/aa/00
XTerm*color11:    rgb:aa/aa/00
XTerm*color12:    rgb:00/00/aa
XTerm*color13:    rgb:aa/00/aa
XTerm*color14:    rgb:00/aa/aa
XTerm*color15:    rgb:ff/ff/ff

Emacs.FontBackend: xft
```

My menu file:

```
[begin] (Fluxbox)
  [exec] (Terminal klein) { xterm -fa Hack:size=10 } <>
  [exec] (Terminal groß) { xterm -fa Hack:size=13 } <>
  [exec] (Datei-Manager) { pcmanfm } <>
  [exec] (Editor) { emacs } <>
  [exec] (Firefox) { LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 firefox } <>
  [exec] (Chromium) { LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 chromium } <>
  [exec] (Uhr) { xclock -bg tan } <>
  [submenu] (Standard-Menü) {}
    [include] (/etc/X11/fluxbox/fluxbox-menu)
  [end]
  [exit] (Exit)
[end]
```